# Django: field's default value from model instance

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to get the last_name and first_name of the newly created user and create the foldername using both values.

But I get type object 'User' has no attribute 'first_name'

This is my Users model:

```
def create_folder_name(first_name, last_name):
    return first_name + last_name


class User(AbstractUser):
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True,
                                   default=create_folder_name(User.first_name, User.last_name))
```

How can I pass the User.first_name to my function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `default` is constructed from other field values, you need to have a model instance to get the values.

[Override the `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.folder_name:
            self.folder_name = create_folder_name(self.first_name, self.last_name)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off overriding the `save` method in your `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.folder_name = create_folder_name(self.first_name, self.last_name)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```